# php $_GET will echo, but appears blank after that

Tags: php, get

I feel like this is pretty straight forward. I have a $_GET like this:

```
$cameFromCat = $_GET['cat'];
echo $cameFromCat;
```

This will read out 'Cards' as expected, so later I ask for it like this:

```
if ($_POST['submission'] == "Continue Shopping") {

    Header("location: index.php?cat=" . $cameFromCat);

}
```

The link sends me to `index.php?cat=`.
It does not read out 'Cards'. However, if I hard code the var like:

```
 $cameFromCat = "Cards";
```

the link sends me to index.php?cat=Cards

It's seriously driving me mad. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: The surrounding code:

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cameFromCat = $_GET['cat'];
$cameFromPage = $_GET['pagenum'];
$action = $_GET['action'];
$cardqty2 = $_POST['var'];

switch ($action) {
case 'add':
    if ($cart) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $cardqty2; $i++) {
            $cart .= ','.$_GET['id'];
        }
    } else {
        $cart = $_GET['id'];
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $cardqty2; $i++) {
            $cart .= ','.$_GET['id'];
        }
    }
    break;
case 'delete':
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($_GET['id'] != $item) {
                if ($newcart != '') {
                    $newcart .= ','.$item;
                } else {
                    $newcart = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        $cart = $newcart;
    }
    break;
case 'update':

    if ($_POST['submission'] == "Update") {

    if ($cart) {
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (stristr($key,'qty')) {
                $id = str_replace('qty','',$key);
                $items = ($newcart != '') ? explode(',',$newcart) : explode(',',$cart);
                $newcart = '';
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if ($id != $item) {
                        if ($newcart != '') {
                            $newcart .= ','.$item;
                        } else {
                            $newcart = $item;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for ($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$id;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $cart = $newcart;
    break;

}

if ($_POST['submission'] == "Checkout") {

 Header("Location: address.php");

}

if ($_POST['submission'] == "Continue Shopping") {

 Header("location: index.php?cat=" . $cameFromCat);

}
```

}

Comment: Display more of your code, because this is not much to go on. You must be resetting the variable somewhere.

Comment: whats happening between your echo and your if statement?

Comment: Are you `POST`ing to a URL that includes the `GET` variable?

Comment: Make sure that you're passing $cameFromCat as an argument if your header() call is in a function

Comment: @Dan - I saw that afterwards and deleted my comment :-)

Comment: maybe it didn't come from cat? darn dogs...

Comment: You maybe were to curious? Curiosity killed the cat ;-)

Comment: @MarkBaker you were right, i had a function later on being called by the submit button that i needed to pass this through. If you submit an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all POST and GET values have been sent properly to your script:

```
// check if GET['cat'] isset
if(!isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    die('GET.cat not set');
}

// check if POST['submissuion'] isset    
if(!isset($_POST['submission'])) {
   die('POST.submission not set');
}

$cameFromCat = $_GET['cat'];
echo $cameFromCat;

if ($_POST['submission'] == "Continue Shopping") {
    Header("location: index.php?cat=" . $cameFromCat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the switch-condition.

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
case 'update':

    if ($_POST['submission'] == "Update") {

    if ($cart) {
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (stristr($key,'qty')) {
                $id = str_replace('qty','',$key);
                $items = ($newcart != '') ? explode(',',$newcart) : explode(',',$cart);
                $newcart = '';
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if ($id != $item) {
                        if ($newcart != '') {
                            $newcart .= ','.$item;
                        } else {
                            $newcart = $item;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for ($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$id;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $cart = $newcart;
    break;

}
```

the break; is inside of the `if ($_POST['submission'] == "Update")`

Another issue is that *one **}** is missing* that surrounds the switch-statement.

My qualified guess would be that you want the code changed to:

```
case 'update':
    if ($_POST['submission'] == "Update") {

    if ($cart) {
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (stristr($key,'qty')) {
                $id = str_replace('qty','',$key);
                $items = ($newcart != '') ? explode(',',$newcart) : explode(',',$cart);
                $newcart = '';
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if ($id != $item) {
                        if ($newcart != '') {
                            $newcart .= ','.$item;
                        } else {
                            $newcart = $item;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for ($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$id;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $cart = $newcart;

    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: @Raidenace - that's up to you :-)